# configuring ssh-agent

Tags: ssh-agent

I'm using ssh-agent for caching private keys; it's working well before connecting remote PC its not asking for a PASSPHRASE but its asking remote user password. 
Ex:

```
host$ sudo ssh-agent bash 
      sudo ssh localhost2.localdomain
```

after that its not asking passphrase its asking only remote user password.

Comment: Welcome to U&L! I updated the text your question slighty, but I also removed all 4 or 5 OS tags that you added, then added the more appropriate ssh-agent tag. That will help you find the people who can best help you.

Answer (score 2):

With that `sudo`, you are switching user to root.  I suspect that was not intended, as ssh will then go looking for keys in /root/.ssh/ and, finding no applicable key there, will just ask for remote user password.

I usually run `exec ssh-agent bash` or similar – remaining then with my own user.

And then I run `ssh-add`, to load (most of) my keys into the agent, before running ssh – again usually without `sudo`.

If I'm wrong, and the `sudo` was intentional, can you tell us what you are trying to achieve thereby?